# how to count a specific letter on a sentence on c#?

Tags: c#

a program that receives a sentence on a string and receives a letter on char and then it counts the number of the same letter that we received (the solution must be on Recursion on c#)

```
namespace recorse
{
    class Program
    {
        static double countc(string s, string c)
        {
            int n = 0, h, count = 0, l = 0;
            h = s.Length;
            if (l != h)
            {
                s = s.Substring(n, l);
                l++; n++;
                if (s == c)
                {
                    count++;
                    return (countc(s, c));
                }
            }
            return (count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the issue you are facing with this code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make this recursive, you should think how to split it and process each part of the problem the same way, and also the corner cases.

I have written the recursive function below, and I will try my best to explain. I am guessing this is homework, so please don't skip the explanation.

**Explanation:**

You have your character (c) to find in the sentence (sentence).
The solution will be the same for each step, but the corner case is with an empty sentence, where it has 0 occurences of your character.

In each recursive step, you want to split the problem. The easiest solution will be to split the sentence to its first character and the rest of the sentence. So the solution will be the sum of: 
a) whether the first character matches or not and
b) the occurences of your character in the rest of the sentence.

**Recursive Function:**

```
    static int CountChar (char c, string sentence)
    {
        if (sentence.Length == 0) return 0;

        var firstLetter = sentence[0];
        var restOfSentence = sentence.Substring(1);
        int count = firstLetter.Equals(c) ? 1 : 0;
        return count + CountChar(c, restOfSentence);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can calculate the count of the character in the text by Recursion:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CountChar("asdasdasdasd",'a'));
        Console.WriteLine(CountChar("asdasdasdasdbb", 'b'));
    }

    public static int CountChar(string text, char character)
    {
        if(text.Length==1)
        {
            if (text[0] == character)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return (text[0] == character ? 1 : 0) + CountChar(text.Substring(1), character);
        }

    }
```